# How can I prevent dpkg-buildpackage from modifying the modification date of the /debian directory when building a Debian package?

Tags: apt, dpkg, packaging, debian

I have set up a working `pbuilder` toolchain for building Debian packages in `i386` and `amd64` varieties for Ubuntu. I am using `reprepro` to manage my own private apt repository and `dupload` to upload `.changes`, `.dsc`, `.deb`, `.orig.tar.gz` and `.debian.tar.gz` files into it. All of this is well documented and it works.

But I am failing to upload the `i386` version of one package together with the `amd64` version of the same package. Reprepro complains with the following message:

```
File "pool/main/p/package/package_1.0.dsc" is already registered with different checksums!
```

The source of the generated `i368` and `amd64` binary packages are exactly the same and have not been modified by me. How can it be that there is a different checksum?

I investigated and discovered that the checksum difference of the `.dsc` file is because it contains a differing checksum of the file `package_1.0.debian.tar.gz`.

Further investigations showed that the `package_1.0.debian.tar.gz` file has indeed different checksums every time `dpkg-buildpackage` is invoked by the debian build toolchain. The reason is that it changes the modification time of the `/debian` subdirectory of a Debian package. The `tar` program unfortunately includes the modification time into the resulting archive, leading to different checksums every time the toolchain is run.

So, my question is: How can I prevent `dpkg-buildpackage` from modifying the modification date of the `/debian` directory when building a Debian package?

If I could do that, the checksum of the files `package_1.0.debian.tar.gz` and `package_1.0.dsc` would stay constant, and I could painlessly upload to `reprepro`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not in exactly the same situation as you, but hopefully my answer can point to what you need.

Rather than using `pbuilder` I'm currently using multiple chroots for building packages on `amd64` and `i386`. I generate the .dsc outside of the chroots using `debuild -S`, then copy the appropriate files to the chroots. Not the best way of doing it I realise.

Inside the first chroot I run `dpkg-buildpackage -b` to build the binary packages. In the second chroot I run `dpkg-buildpackage -B`, to only build the architecture dependent packages - i.e. those that aren't duplicated.

When I use `reprepro` to push the packages to my repo, the .debs from the first chroot (i386) with target "all" are copied to all architectures as well as the `i386` debs being copied to `i386`. When I push the packages from the second chroot (amd64), the remaining architecture dependent debs or `amd64` are copied across.

Answer (score 0):

You could try overriding tar command and adding `--mtime=some_fixed_time` argument to it.

Answer (score 0):

Afaict you can't really.

The debian packaging system uses the "debian" directory both as a place to store package metadata long term and as a place to store various build artifacts temporarily during the build process. There has been a bunch of work on making the building of Binary packages reproducible, but I haven't heard of any similar efforts for source packages.

The proper solution to your errors is to only build the source package and the arch all binary packages once. Then for the second architecture you should only build the architecture dependent binary packages. For pbuilder you want the "--binary-arch" option.